# How to protect data of users in multi-user site?

Tags: sql-injection, databases

I am working on a system where people can make their accounts with few things being stored in database like id (that will be auto increment), first name, last name, username etc.

Now I am well aware of SQL injections, so I am using prepared statements, but is prepared statement alone enough to prevent attackers from tampering with my database?

Everybody knows the first name and last name of people on social networks and that could be used:

```
`delete from table where firstname='john'`
```

or can be done same with id as it is auto increment we can write down any number

```
`update table set firstname='joker' where id=555`.
```

So my question is are prepared statements enough to prevent sql attacks or professionals store such information in database in encrypted form.

Answer (score 2):

> Are prepared statements enough to prevent SQL injection attacks?

Doubtful, I would not rely on prepared statements only. Input validation is still required and highly recommended. Determine what input you expect in a field and act on it accordingly.

For example, in a name field you should not expect characters such as ">" or "<". However, a character like a quote is expected and should be properly dealt with.

> Do professionals store such information in database in encrypted form?

This depends on the type of data and its classification, generally not all fields are encrypted. In case of credit cards for example, they are required to be encrypted.

The location of the decryption key is another thing to consider. If the key is stored on the same machine where the encrypted tables are stored, an attacker could possibly get this key as well.

A SQL injection attack can also lead to shell access and does not necessarily always mean the extraction of the data located in the database. If the key is stored on the same machine, an attacker could retrieve both the encrypted data and the decryption key.

**Note:** Encrypting data in a database should not be considered a solution for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: SQL Injection relies on an attacker being able to execute arbitrary SQL commands. How would this be possible if all SQL statements are prepared?

Comment: Validating inputs is still extremely important, but this is mostly to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using prepared statements everywhere in your code, then SQL injection should not be possible.

SQL injection is just one means of attack though. You also need to ensure that your site is secure against other forms of attack. Most importantly you have to ensure it's not possible to upload executable files etc.